# Why do we write $800 but say "800 dollars"

Tags: etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In which case are items written in a different order than they are read aloud?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66462/in-which-case-are-items-written-in-a-different-order-than-they-are-read-aloud)

Why don't we write "800 $"? This would be more straightforward -- just as we speak it.